# How to remedy OutOfMemory exception with impossibly long string in c#?

Tags: c#, string, recursion

I got an assignment where I have to come up with a code that continues to create unbelievably long strings and I can't figure out how to get around the issue of simply running out of memory by going beyond the limits of a simple string.

The program asks for the following from the user:

- A: string that will be its first "real" input (e.g. "a", "asdf", etc.)
- B: "base" string with special characters that can be substituted by A (e.g. "%n%", "%abc%def%, %%asd%tr, etc.)
- C: number of times the program should run (up to 1 billion)
- D: first index of a character from the final string
- E: last index of a char from the final string - these are to return to the user with something.

The catch is, with every iteration, A should be updated to whatever output is produced when substituting it into B, and then it's used as an input again.

An example would be 1) *ana* (A: a, B: %n%) 2) *ananana* (A: ana, B: %n%) 3) *ananananananana* (A: ananana, B: %n%) etcetc, and then with D & E being 3 & 7 respectively, the final output would be *anana*.

Another would be with A: x, B: %a%b%c%, C: 999999999, D: 33, E: 65 --> *xaxbxcxaxaxbxcxbxaxbxcxcxaxbxcxbx*

One more: A: abcdef, B: %%, C:500, D: 3, E: 22 --> *cdefabcdefabcdefabcdef*

And like a simple one, A: hi, B: %hey, C: 10, D: 10, E: 20 --> *eyheyheyhey*

I've been trying to solve it by creating a separate class and running what I think is a form of recursion (although I'm not 100% sure, I'm very much a beginner) but despite my best efforts, I keep getting the OOM error once the string reaches what I assume must be past a string's limit. Maybe I've been trying to approach the whole problem from the wrong angle? But at this point I can't envision a different path I could've taken towards a solution.

Here's what I have so far - would really appreciate any help from anyone!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BehindTheScenes trial = new BehindTheScenes(Console.ReadLine(), Console.ReadLine(),
             int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

        trial.ReWrite();

        Console.WriteLine(trial.Display());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}
class BehindTheScenes
{
    public string InAndOut { get; set; }

    public string specialchar { get; set; }

    public int no_of_times { get; set; }

    public int min { get; set; }

    public int max { get; set; }

    public int counter { get; set; }

    public BehindTheScenes(string substitute, string specialchar, int no_of_times, int min, int max)
    {
        this.InAndOut = substitute;
        this.specialchar = specialchar;
        this.no_of_times = no_of_times;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    public void ReWrite()
    {
        if (this.specialchar.Contains("$"))
        {
            string temp = "";

            while (counter < this.no_of_times)
            {
                temp = this.specialchar.Replace("$", this.InAndOut);
                this.InAndOut = temp;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }


    public string Display()
    {
        int total_length = this.max - this.min + 1;
        string dash = new string('-', 99);
        string final = "";

        if (!this.specialchar.Contains("$"))
        {
            if (this.min > this.specialchar.Length)
            {
                return dash.Substring(0, total_length);
            }
            else
            {
                final = string.Concat(this.specialchar, dash);
                return final.Substring(this.min - 1, total_length);
            }
        }

        if (this.max > this.InAndOut.Length)
        {
            
            final = string.Concat(this.InAndOut, dash);
            return final.Substring(this.min - 1, total_length);
            
        }
        else
        {
            return this.InAndOut.Substring(this.min - 1, total_length);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I must admit I'm looking at this one my phone while out and about, but aren't you looking to create an array? You cut up the long string into multiple objects so that you circumvent the massive memory hog of just 1 variable.

Comment: at this moment, what I've done is I've saved the output from every iteration into a string array, the problem though is that after a while the individual string (on like the 500th index for example) becomes so large that the system just cannot handle it anymore. And since the substitute characters can be anywhere in B (which can consist of 50 chars total), I can't really identify a pattern that would be applicable to all instances either. Or maybe I'm just not imaginative enough. :(

Comment: Is the base string a variable? or is it always %n%? Also your example is contradictory, applying %n% should give a, ana, ananana, etc... not anaaana. In which case the answer is obvious: if index is even value is n otherwise a. It looks like more an CS algorithm problem that you need to solve in another way than brute force.

Comment: Can you give an exact example of input values you are using

Comment: Also I really can't figure out what "and then with D & E being 3 & 7 respectively, the final output would be aaana." is meaning.

Comment: the base string is variable yes, it's based on user input, and can be pretty much anything. %sdfgs%as%, %%%, fs%se%, etcetc., and yeah I did mess up my example sorry, little late here haha - edited it to actually make sense. D would be a starting "index" from the final string, here the third letter, 'a', and E would be the last, so we'd want characters 3 to 7 (where the first character in the final string is 1)

Comment: I mean, I am trying to figure out what to input when I run this. and what makes sense

Comment: @TheGeneral, for instance, A: x, B: %a%b%c%, C: 1500, D: 3, E: 15

Comment: Is there a set of test cases you can verify your solution with? If yes then better to include them in question

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now.

Comment: Again, I believe it is impossible to really solve this by brute force (i.e. simply calculating the result), because even rather simple cases are growing very quickly. On each iteration. With N the number of placeholders in your base string, and i the number of iteration, it is growing at an N^i rate, which is rapidly gigantic. So to me it is more a math problem than a programming one.

Comment: This would appear to be a coding challenge, which usually come up with relatively easy examples with low iterations, but as soon as the iterations go up, you'll find that your approach wasn't correct. Brute-forcing those exercises almost never works, you'll need to find an algorithm, a way of calculating the output without actually running the input millions of times through the replacement cycle.

Comment: Looks like more a question for Math.StackExchange. Perhaps mentioning Fractals? but I'm out of my league.

Comment: Here is the deal, if this ends in a chaotic expression, then brute force is your only option. To solve the out of memory error, you will need to use files or some other facility to back your mutating result. I use the word chaotic specifically, and you will need to read up on why a function can result like this to know why its never possible to solve other than brute force.  However, if you can constrain the inputs, meaning if you can give certain guarantees about what are valid inputs, you can likely calculate this without the brute force iterations.

Comment: At the moment, because the substitute and patterns can contain both the replacement character, and are them selves unconstrained then this will end chaotically. Your strings can grow exponentially, and small numbers of iterations can potentially be longer than all the atoms in the universe

Comment: Thanks for the insight @TheGeneral. It makes sense.

Comment: Side note, you dont need the array, on your while should just be a simple for loop

Comment: Further note, even with a chaotic result, there are means to zoom in to a target in certain circumstances, and becomes a math problem

Comment: One thing to note is that the `string` class is immutable. Every time you "change" a string, the result is a new instance of a string object (the old instance is likely no longer referenced and eligible for garbage collection). Any object over 85 kbyte is considered a _Large Object_ (and, since strings use 2 bytes/character, that means any string over 43k long).  Large objects are managed differently than small objects. They can only be collected by expensive Gen2 collections. If you start spinning off a lot of large objects, your garbage collection will overwhelm you app. OEM is not uncommon

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone! :) I've tried tackling the issue from another direction and wrote a method that would count the total number of characters of the final string without actually producing it, thinking that I could use that number to check if it's beyond a string's maxvalue (and if so, just go until I reach the min index), but now I'm getting a stackoverflow error for larger values on C, so once again, back to the drawing board for me haha. Getting a little discouraged if I'm being honest - I'm sure the solution's got something to do with the min-max thing but I just cant find it